# Reference for projective limits of Banach Spaces..

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have just started studying a book about pseudo-differential operators and I came across **projective limits** of Banach spaces and I got lost. I have never studied this, so can anyone recommend me some nice references to get started to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These notes](http://www.math.utah.edu/~taylor/LCS.pdf) by Taylor discuss this particular construction.

More generally, this falls into the very deep, rich theory of locally convex topological vector spaces. Good places to start include the book *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels* by Treves as well as early works by Grothendieck (in particular, his book *Topological Vector Spaces* or Bourbaki's book of the same title).